# Trigger Events Inside Anonymous Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm trying to create an anonymous object that will append a new canvas element to the DOM. This all works fine, but when I try to register an event with JQuery on the newly appended canvas from within the Object it does not trigger.

I believe it has something to do with the scope, but how would one go about registering these events?

```
var game_grid;

$(function() {
    game_grid = new GameGrid();
});

(function (window) {

    function GameGrid() {
        this.initialize();
    }

    GameGrid.prototype.canvas;
    GameGrid.prototype.ctx;

    GameGrid.prototype.initialize = function() {
        // Append Child to DOM element
        this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        this.canvas.width = $(".game-grid-container").width();
        this.canvas.height = $(".game-grid-container").height();
        this.canvas.id = "game_grid";
        $(".game-grid-container").html(this.canvas);

        // Define Canvas' Context
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

        // Set Up Touch Listeners
        $(this.canvas).on("vmousedown vmousemove vmouseup", function(e) {
            alert("Not Triggering!");
        });
    }

    window.GameGrid = GameGrid;

} (window));
```

Comment: `$(".game-grid-container").html(this.canvas);` seems wrong. `.html()` expects a string, and you pass a DOM element. `$(".game-grid-container").append(this.canvas);` sounds better.

Comment: Both `append()` and `html()` will work if the element I am adding the element to is empty. If it isn't, then `append()` will retain the existing code and `html()` will clear it.

Comment: Actually, after looking a the source code, `e.html(DOMElement)` is equivalent to `e.empty().append(DOMElement)`, so this shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @FelixKling OK, I was only looking in the docs.

Comment: @kapa: Sure, I wouldn't advice passing DOM elements to `.html` either. I was just curious what's really happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer I found was to stray away from JQuery all together and bind the event with the addEventListener function. I'm sure there is a way to do this with JQuery, but I can confirm this works.

```
(function (window) {

    function GameGrid() {
        this.initialize();
    }

    GameGrid.prototype.canvas;
    GameGrid.prototype.ctx;
    GameGrid.prototype.background_color = '#F0F0F0';
    GameGrid.prototype.grid_line_color = '#D9D9D9';
    GameGrid.prototype.horizontal_division = 8;
    GameGrid.prototype.vertical_division = 8;

    /* Public Functions */
    GameGrid.prototype.initialize = function() {
        // Append Child to DOM
        this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        this.canvas.width = $('.game-grid-container').width();
        this.canvas.height = $('.game-grid-container').height();
        this.canvas.id = 'game_grid';
        $('.game-grid-container').append(this.canvas);

        // Define Canvas' Context
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

        // Set Up Touch Listeners
        document.getElementById('game_grid').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
            alert('triggering!');
        });
    }

    window.GameGrid = GameGrid;

} (window));
```